# How to perform uncertainty propagation for operations inside a matrix

Tags: error-propagation

Assume you are given a matrix **U** with $u_{i,j}$ being the value of **U** at location $i,j$ and $\delta u_{i,j}$ being the uncertainty of **U** at $i,j$ (uncertainty implying noise in the estimate).  If I perform the following simple operation (for example) at each $i,j$ location, what would be the output uncertainty.

$$
o_{i,j} = \frac{(u_{i,j} - u_{i+1, j} + u_{i-1,j} - u_{i,j-1} + u_{i, j+1})}{k}
$$

where $o_{i,j}$ is the output **O** at $i,j$ with $k$ being some constant.

I have the following the questions.

1. If I wish to perform uncertainty estimation on the output $\delta o_{i,j}$, how to perform for such an operation.
2. Also, if I wish to do proper uncertainties where I assume I know the input variance-covariance matrix which implies that I have input covariances between $u_{i,j}$ and $u_{i+1,j}$, $u_{i,j}$ and $u_{i,j+1}$ and so on.., then how does the output value vary at $\delta o_{i,j}$

How does the error propagate in both cases.

Comment: You haven't properly defined what you mean by uncertainties. Are the $u_{i,j}$ random variables with known (means and) variances?

Comment: In my case, the uncertainty is noise in the input. Sorry for not mentioning that properly.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty

Answer (score 1):

If by uncertainty you mean a variance then you can use the [Sum of correlated variables rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_correlated_variables) (plus the [scaling rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties)): $${\rm VAR}(o_{i,j}) = \frac{1}{k^2} \left({\rm VAR}(u_{i,j}) +{\rm VAR}(u_{i+1,j})+{\rm VAR}(u_{i-1,j})+{\rm VAR}(u_{i,j+1})+{\rm VAR}(u_{i,j}-1) - {\rm COV}(u_{i,j},u_{i+1,j}) + {\rm COV}(u_{i,j},u_{i-1,j}))- {\rm COV}(u_{i,j},u_{i,j-1}) + {\rm COV}(u_{i,j},u_{i,j+1})) \pm ...\right),$$

where the covariance terms go between all pairs and they carry the sign of the product terms (while all variance terms are positive).

Comment: In my case, the uncertainty is noise in the input. Sorry for not mentioning that properly.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty

Comment: That seems to fit what I wrote. If every value is uncertain, it is assigned to a variance ${\rm VAR}(u_{i,j}) = \delta u_{i,j}$. These propagate according to the sum of correlated variables rule, as I wrote...